# Position one end of Line on a Circle in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

So I need to recreate a radar type effect. I have one point of my line in the center of my screen, and the other reaches out to edge of my radar screen.

I want to use a QDial to control the position of the second point of my line.

I'm just not sure on the math I need to use to keep that second point locked, so to speak, on the edge of the screen as the QDial moves it around.

Thanks in advance.

[Added info]

So here is how I'm adding the line to my scene. Tying in the angle of the line to my QDial handles all the math for me perfectly, but it overdraws another line with each turn of the dial, instead of just adjusting the angle of the one line.

```
void Radar::drawMainLine(){
     QPainter linePainter;
     linePainter.begin(this);
     linePainter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

     QPen mainline(Qt::yellow);
     mainline.setWidth(3);

     QLineF line (QPointF(400,400), QPointF(0,0) );
     line.setAngle(m_QDial_rotation);

     m_RadarScene->addLine(line, mainline);
   }
```

How can I adjust my one line's angle?

I see that I should be able to affect just the position of one of the end points of the line but I think this is going to take me back down the path of needing an algorithm in order to process its position.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Very informative for sure, but way above my head Rafael. I don't even know where to start translating all that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `valueChanged` signal, setMaximun value to 359 and setTransformOriginPoint at the start of the line.
In header:

```
private:
    ...
    QGraphicsScene *m_RadarScene;
    QLineF line;
    QGraphicsLineItem *item;
public slots:
    void drawMainLine(int angle);
```

In constructor:

```
connect(ui->m_QDial_rotation, &QDial::valueChanged, this, &Radar::drawMainLine);
ui->m_QDial_rotation->setMaximum(359);
QPointF mCenter = QPointF(ui->graphicsView->size().width()/2, ui->graphicsView->size().height()/2);
int radius = 50;
ui->graphicsView->centerOn(mCenter);
line = QLineF(mCenter, mCenter + QPointF(0, radius) );

item = m_RadarScene->addLine(line, mainline);
item->setTransformOriginPoint(mCenter);
```

onSlot:

```
void Radar::drawMainLine(int angle)
{
    qDebug()<<angle;
    item->setRotation(angle);
}
```

Comment: Including this as the answer since I feel it adds a more correct way of doing this as opposed to how I approached it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a pointer on QLine named m_line for example. This pointer will contain the current line, once ou want to move the line you can make a removeItem (I suppose your radar is a QGraphicsScene) and then add the new line.
like that :

```
 void Radar::drawMainLine(){
         QPainter linePainter;
         linePainter.begin(this);
         linePainter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

         QPen mainline(Qt::yellow);
         mainline.setWidth(3);

         QLineF *line = new QLine(QPointF(400,400), QPointF(0,0) );
         line->setAngle(m_QDial_rotation);
         if (m_line != nullptr)
             m_RadarScene->removeItem(*m_line);
         m_line = line; // add QLine* m_line = nullptr; in your class    
         m_RadarScene->addLine(*line, mainline);
       }
```

Comment: Thanks, it errors on the removeItem, and addItem:  no matching call to remove or add pointers.

Comment: that worked for the addItem, but it still doesn't like it on the removeItem

Comment: I went with the other answer as the solution because while you were helping me get through this how I approached it, I now see that using a LineItem was a better method.  Thank you though very much